# express regular expression string notation

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, express

I am new to Javascript and regular expressions, so I was kind of stuck on how to make a route match all urls that begin with `/user/....`

I could just do `app.get(/user/, function(req,req){ /*stuff*/});`

But I was wondering how I could do it if I used a string in place of the regex object.  For example

```
app.get("/user/:id", function(req,req){ /*stuff*/});
```

Only matches urls with `"user"` and one parameter.  How would I code it so it matched `"user"` and N parameters

And also whats the difference between using the string or literal javascript regex object?
I have found that even in the string notation I can do something like this...

```
app.get("/user/:d([a-z]*)", function (req, res) {

    //more stuff
});
```

Comment: `get` doesn't work that way... Also if you want to use dynamic string as a regex, then use `RegExp` constructor

Comment: @AmitJoki what do you mean `get` doesnt work that way...A tutorial I was using passed a string as the regex argument of the `get` method

Comment: The difference between using a string and a regexp is that any regexp capture groups are only accessible by index, whereas the string form supports "named capture groups".

Comment: @mscdex is that the only difference? I remember reading somewhere that using regex literals gives you more functionality than just using strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure of a way to pass a single route N parameters. You can however do a few different routes like:

```
var userController = requrie('./user_controller'),
  isAuthenticated = require('./middleware/is_authenticated');

app.get("/user/:id/address/:addressId", userController.addressById);
app.get("/user/:id/address", userController.address);
app.get("/user/:id", userController.index);
```

In order to check for something like authentication before executing the controller action you could use middleware for this and place it as the second parameter before the controller action, which would look something like:

```
app.get("/user/:id", isAuthenticated, userController.index);
```

In the example above your `user_controller.js` would looks something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  index: function(req, res) {
    // index action logic
  },
  address: function(req, res) {
    // address action logic
  },
  addressById: function(req, res) {
    // addressById action logic
  }
};
```

This would allow you to pass similar but different routes to different controller actions which would give you a little more control over how to sort out the different routes, as that is more of the routers job than the controllers job anyway.

One more thing to note is that the order of the routes matter. It's usually best to put more specific routes from a group of routes first and more generic routes last.

Hope that helps!

Comment: what if I wanted every `/user/...`  call to go through one general route(to check if the user is still logged in), it would then make sense to have this as the first route, right?

Comment: Ahhh, I see what you want to do. I'm not sure if there's a way to do that to check for auth, but this blog post has a pretty good explanation of how to route through middleware on particular routes, which could work for you. http://scotch.io/quick-tips/js/node/route-middleware-to-check-if-a-user-is-authenticated-in-node-js

Comment: in my generic `/user/...` I just put `if(!req.session.uname) redirect("/login");` is this a way to check if the user is logged in or not?

Comment: Usually you would store some session variable and a cookie on the users machine that would need to be combined in some way to check that they are really authenticated. But yes, that would more or less work so long as you have stored their username in req.session.uname when they log in. Also, you would need to `res.redirect("/login");` (with the `redirect` method on the `res` object. On a side note, I would strongly suggest that you look into more robust authentication than just checking a session variable.

Comment: oh yeah, i meant `res.redirect`.  Thanks for the help! But what other forms of authentication can I use? Are you talking about something like passportjs?

Comment: Yeah, passport can take a lot of the pain of dealing with authentication away and can be used as middleware also, I believe.